# Postgres `log_disconnections = on` does not log disconnects

Tags: postgresql, configuration

I have surely a basic problem and am undoubtedly overlooking a simple issue..

I have configured Postgres 12.4 with `log_disconnections`, but the log file does not show any disconnects. (It is logging connections, as expected with `log_connections = on`.)

I have connected and disconnected with both `psql` (exiting `psql` with `\quit`) and the Ruby `pg` library.  In both cases, no disconnect message was logged.

During testing, I used `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'foo'` to verify a connection was present (idle) while I was connected, and gone when I quit `psql` or calling pg/Ruby `conn.finish`.

Why isn't the server logging disconnections?

The server configuration is basic:

```
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)

shared_buffers = 128MB          # min 128kB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  # the default is the first option

max_wal_size = 1GB
min_wal_size = 80MB

log_connections = on
log_disconnections = on
log_timezone = 'America/Toronto'

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'America/Toronto'

lc_messages = 'C'           # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'C'           # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'C'            # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'C'               # locale for time formatting

default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

The server log file:

```
2021-01-18 09:36:18.774 EST [45512] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, compiled by Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17), 64-bit
2021-01-18 09:36:18.777 EST [45512] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2021-01-18 09:36:18.777 EST [45512] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2021-01-18 09:36:18.778 EST [45512] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-01-18 09:36:18.825 EST [45513] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-01-18 09:35:38 EST
2021-01-18 09:36:18.828 EST [45512] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2021-01-18 09:44:36.433 EST [45868] LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2021-01-18 09:44:36.434 EST [45868] LOG:  connection authorized: user=testuser database=foo application_name=pry
2021-01-18 09:45:37.299 EST [45962] LOG:  connection received: host=[local]
2021-01-18 09:45:37.300 EST [45962] LOG:  connection authorized: user=testuser database=foo application_name=psql
```

Postgres started with `pg_ctl -l path/to/log -D path/to/pgdir start`.

Comment: To rule out the obvious: you did reload the configuration after changing `postgresql.conf` (or restart Postgres)`

Comment: I completely stopped and restarted the server in fact, (`pg_ctl stop`) to rule that out, yes.

Comment: Maybe there is another line with that setting later in the file. You can check with `select setting, source, sourcefile, sourceline from pg_settings where name = 'log_disconnections'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not in the file, but indeed I found it in `postgresql.auto.conf`.  If you move your comment to an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug non-working configuration settings, you can verify at runtime what the value is, and where it came from by querying the view `pg_settings`

```
select setting, source, sourcefile, sourceline 
from pg_settings 
where name = 'log_disconnections'
```

The columns `sourcefile` and `sourceline` will tell you where the currently active value was taken from.

If you find a value from `postgresql.auto.conf` the value was applied through `ALTER SYSTEM` and the correct way to remove it, is to use `ALTER SYSTEM` again.